# Keras Gpu: Configuration

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm running simple dense layers, but Gpu load and Cpu load is low all the time.
[image]
[image]
**print(device_lib.list_local_devices())**

> 2019-02-19 19:06:23.911633: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
>
> 2019-02-19
>   19:06:24.231261:Itensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432]
>   Found device 0 with properties: name: GeForce RTX 2080 major: 7 minor:
>   5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.83 pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0 totalMemory:
>   8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.55GiB 2019-02-19 19:06:24.237952: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible
>   gpu devices: 0 2019-02-19 19:06:25.765790: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-02-19
>   19:06:25.769303: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0
>   2019-02-19 19:06:25.771334: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
>   2019-02-19 19:06:25.776384: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6288 MB memory) -> physical GPU
>   (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute
>   capability: 7.5) [name: "/device:CPU:0" device_type: "CPU"
>   memory_limit: 268435456 locality { } incarnation: 5007262859900510599
>   , name: "/device:GPU:0" device_type: "GPU" memory_limit: 6594058650
>   locality {   bus_id: 1   links {   } } incarnation:
>   16804701769178738279 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce
>   RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"

At leaset, it is working on GPU. But I don't know if this is max limit to proceduce this deep learning net in this GPU or not.

**EDIT2: dataset**

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/combined+cycle+power+plant

It's about 10000 datapoint and 4 description variables.

**EDIT3: Code, it's really simple.**

```
num_p = 8
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8*num_p, input_dim=input_features, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(16*num_p, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(16*num_p, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(16*num_p, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(16*num_p, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(8*num_p, input_dim=input_features, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0005, patience=200, verbose=0, mode='min')
his = model.fit(x=X_train_scaled, y=y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10000, verbose=0,
validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[es])
```

**EDIT4: input data code**

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(df.iloc[:, :-1].values, df.iloc[:, -1].values)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
batch_size = 64
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_scaled, y_train))
print(dataset)
dataset = dataset.cache()
print(dataset)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train_scaled))
print(dataset)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
print(dataset)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
print(dataset)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size*10)
print(dataset)

<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((4,), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)> 
<CacheDataset shapes: ((4,), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)> 
<ShuffleDataset shapes: ((4,), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)> 
<RepeatDataset shapes: ((4,), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)> 
<BatchDataset shapes: ((?, 4), (?,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)> 
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((?, 4), (?,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
```

Comment: How your input pipeline looks like?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I put the model summary.

Comment: How you input data to your model? What kind of data do you train on?

Comment: I meant how your code looks like? What function do you use to feed data to your model?

Comment: How you get these `x=X_train_scaled, y=y_train` ?

Comment: After removing outlier, use MinMaxscaler for X_train_scaled. And y_train is raw data.

Comment: How do you read excel file with data?

Comment: By pandas read_csv

Comment: Could you please show full code of how you read data file

Comment: Which information do you need to diagnose problem?

Comment: Problem is obviously in your input pipeline. I need to see how is it constructed.

Comment: I put the input code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase GPU utilization by increasing batch size. However, considering rather small dataset size, performance can still be improved by using Dataset API. It's much more scalable solution, capable of handling large datasets.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_scaled, y_train))
dataset = dataset.cache() #caches dataset in memory
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train_scaled)) #shuffles dataset
dataset = dataset.repeat() #with no parameter, repeats indefinitely
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size*10) #prefetches data
```

Then you just pass dataset object to `model.fit` with no batch_size, cause it was specified earlier and with steps_per_epoch to let the model know the size of epoch.

```
his = model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=7500, epochs=1000)
```

p.s. With csv file of this size it's hard to get high utilization rate. You can easily pass whole dataset as one batch and get about 60%. More info here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

Comment: I got error, `AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'.` I just added your code after my input code. I saw the official guide, but I don't understand clearly yet. this dataset has  data itself?

Comment: This error is from model.fit, it means most likely, wrong data type prior to dataset. Shapes seem to be ok, ? in dimension means batch size. 
 Dataset feeds data to the model, keras or estimator handle iteration. Try evaluating dataset with tf.Session to check data correctness. 

`iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()`

`with tf.Session() as sess:
 print(sess.run(iterator.get_next()))`

Comment: output is `(array([[0.61614731, 0.45118483, 0.23880228, 0.58324397]]), array([443.02]))` it seems ok?

Comment: tf.shape should output [batch_size, num_columns]

Comment: In increasing batch_size, the output also increase. Somehow it's working.

Comment: It's strange cause I get no  error. What is the output of 
`arr = iterator.get_next()[0]
print(sess.run(tf.shape(arr)))` ?

Comment: '[10  4]' in setting batch_size = 10

Comment: and with `arr = iterator.get_next()[1]`?
how this line `his = model.fit(...)` looks like?

Comment: `print(type(X_train_scaled))` and same for y_train  should output 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: X_train_scaled:`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`(7104, 4),y_train `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`(7104,)  () is shape of data.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Try populating dataframe(same shape as original) with random data using `np.random.randint(1,100, len(dataframe))` and pass it to your pipeline. If it works, it means that something's wrong with datatypes in your initial dataframe

Comment: It seems it's not problem on my data. Which version of Keras and tensor are you using? My keras is 2.2.4, tensor is 1.12.0. I recreate the question for this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the wrong display to see GPU usage with tensorflow. What you are seeing is the 3D activity of  the video card.

If you notice there is a drop down arrow next to 3D, Video Encode etc. Set one of them to Cuda and the other to Copy. This allows you to see the compute usage and copying time.

I actually have a similar type of problem I am working on where I get about 65% usage under Cuda because the dataset is so small. You can increase the batch size to increase GPU usage but you also hurt the net as a result so it really is better to train on data sets with a batch size around 32-128 for most things even if your GPU memory will work on far more.

The answer above for using Datasets should work if you can figure out how to get it working right. That is something I am working on now.